# ArcGIS integration with OpenText eDocs DM?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, arcgis-silverlight-api

I work for a municipality and all of our internal documents are stored in a Document Management system, OpenText eDocs DM. 
I would like that in my internal Mapping Application (ArcGIS Server / Silverlight API), I could link my Parcels with its legal documentation stored in eDocs.

Has anyone been able to implement such a thing?

Comment: Yes, on many occasions. There are lots of ways you can do this. Just need to establish the connections between your parcels and there identifiers and create the UI you want to use to display the appropriate information. Not that complex at all in the big picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a past job, we implemented something similar with the internal LiveLink document management system (DMS) (which Googling that it seems that it is an OpenText product). With LiveLink, every document in the system had a URL, as the system was both web-based and had a plugin for Windows Explorer. We were linking to well records, and the folder structure in the DMS was very structured so that we could simply pass in a well ID number to the URL (can't remember if it was through a querystring or just folder names) and get back the documents we wanted. We had a procedure that would run nightly and update a hyperlink field in the featureclass to build the URLs. Worked like a charm in both desktop and web applications. If your system is web-based, you should be able to implement something similar.

Comment: I will try this approach, and share my discoveries.  Did you have to build your own document launcher?

Comment: @DominicDoiron - I've had a chance to think about this some more. Since LiveLink was web based, we would build a URL to a _folder_ that contained the documents a user would want. Then, when they clicked on the link, it opened up the LiveLink application in IE, where they would then grab the documents. No custom launcher necessary, as the hyperlinks we built launched the default web browser, then LiveLink handled the rest from there.

Comment: Do you know if a licence of the ECM is requiered for LiveLink?

Comment: I think the way it worked for us was that it passed your Windows credentials through to LiveLink. I'm sure there was some sort of ELA in place as well. For your installations, is there a local LiveLink client installed on the PC? You might want to get with whoever is in charge of LiveLink and get their take.